# "dramatiq test.py" fails with "'test' is not a package"

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, dramatiq

need some help
Can't start using dramatiq because some errors

My structure is

```
projectDirectory/apptest/
  __init__.py  (Eempty file. Not really empty, all lines commented with #)
  test.py
```

I'm using Conda environment with dramatiq installed via pip

#--- test.py has the following code

```
import dramatiq

@dramatiq.actor
def lenstring(txt):
  print(len(txt))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  lenstring.send("hello")
```

Problem is...
1- Loading environment using conda activate
2- Running dramatiq from apptest in order to start worker

```
$ dramatiq test.py
[2023-07-26 14:29:19,622] [PID 4664] [MainThread] [dramatiq.MainProcess] [INFO] Dramatiq '1.14.2' is booting up.
[2023-07-26 14:29:18,621] [PID 4666] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(0)] [ERROR] Failed to import module.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dramatiq/cli.py", line 382, in worker_process
    module, broker = import_broker(args.broker)
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dramatiq/cli.py", line 123, in import_broker
    module, broker_or_callable = import_object(value)
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dramatiq/cli.py", line 112, in import_object
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 970, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.py'; 'test' is not a package
[2023-07-26 14:29:19,624] [PID 4664] [MainThread] [dramatiq.MainProcess] [CRITICAL] Worker with PID 4666 exited unexpectedly (code 2). Shutting down...
[2023-07-26 14:29:18,618] [PID 4667] [MainThread] [dramatiq.WorkerProcess(1)] [ERROR] Failed to import module.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dramatiq/cli.py", line 382, in worker_process
    module, broker = import_broker(args.broker)
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dramatiq/cli.py", line 123, in import_broker
    module, broker_or_callable = import_object(value)
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dramatiq/cli.py", line 112, in import_object
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "/home/yo/anaconda3/envs/BotAI/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 970, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.py'; 'test' is not a package
$
```

I don't understad how to solve the problem, can someone help me?

I try to start a dramatiq worker, the code is just a simplyfied variation of some example I found on the web. I have a much more complex code to run but can't event start with this simple one (The errors on the complex code is basically the same)

Answer (score 1):

When using the dramatiq command, you shouldn't use the ".py" file extension. Type it out like you would if you were importing something.

In your case it would be:
`dramatiq test`